# Username and password check not working. Eclispse GUI

Tags: java

I have a GUI in eclipse where I enter username and password and if they are correct when I press a Jbutton, the GUI should close. Else say "Wrong username and password". My code is:

```
if(name == username.getText() && pass == Password.getText()){
                    //allow access
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else{
                    //deny
                    btnLogIn.setText("Wrong username or password");
                }
```

I keep getting the "Wrong username or password" although the username and password are 100% correct. Where am I going wrong?

Variables:
    private JPasswordField Password;
    private JTextField username;

```
private String id = "username";
private String pass = "pass";
```

Comment: Why is that `Password` uppercase ? Also, the String are compared like follows: `name.equals( username.getText() )`

Comment: Just the variable name, I edited the question to show the variable names there.

Comment: Thanks works perfect after using the .equals()